# How to input tabular data and output circular packing plot?

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

Really confused about what input I should be using, I can't work it out from the example data set.

I have a data set like this:

```
node1   node2   edge_score
x1      x2      0.1
x1      x3      0.2
x8      x4      0.1
x4      x5      0.4
x6      x7      0.5
```

(In real life, the score is an indication of how similar two nodes are).

I want to plot these in one of [these](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/313-basic-circle-packing-with-several-levels.html) circle packing graphs.

But I can't work out how to input my data (because I guess here I can two vertices, node A and node B?) compared to the flare data set that they use as an example.

So the input should be the table above and the output should be a bubble plot (one giant circle) with three smaller sub-circles:

```
One circle has x1, x2 and x3
one circle has x8, x4 and x5
one circle has x6 and x7
```

if it was possible incorporate the edge score into the size of the circles that would be great but I don't see how edges are included in this analysis, but then, they are read into the example? Or I guess even if someone could demonstrate how to change the node size generally if I added another column with some node size or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `ggraph` indicates that the "circlepacking" is basically a treemap, so the graph should reflect a hierarchy.

Your graph, as defined, produces three unconnected groups:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)

df <- read.table(text="node1   node2   edge_score
x1      x2      0.1
x1      x3      0.2
x8      x4      0.1
x4      x5      0.4
x6      x7      0.5", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  df,
  directed = TRUE
)

ggraph(g, layout = "auto") +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image: three unconnected groups]

If I modify this a bit, I try to get closer to the plot you asked (not exactly by close):

```
df <- read.table(text="node1   node2   edge_score
x1      x2      0.1
x1      x3      0.2
x2      x6      0.1
x2      x7      0.3
x3      x4      0.1
x4      x5      0.4
x4      x8      0.5", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  df,
  directed = TRUE
)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(
  df,
  directed = TRUE
)

V(g)$r = 1

ggraph(g, layout = "auto") +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_fixed()

ggraph(g, layout = "circlepack") +
  geom_edge_link() +
  geom_node_circle() +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name)) +
  coord_fixed()
```

The graph is more "tree-like"

[image: new graph]

And it "circlepacks" a bit better

[image: circlepacked graph]

HTH